# Bokeh Tooltip: grid view, rather than list-view

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a dataset with 1000s of samples. If I plot a scatter plot and hover over a crowded area, the tooltip becomes extremely long and reaches out of the screen. Is there a way to hack the css of the tooltip to display a 2D grid of the individual tooltip `<div>`s rather than a vertical list?

Comment: You can use the customized tooptip, then you have full control with style class and css.

Comment: I tried that, but I am not good in html/css. I have tried to find out in the Bokeh code where I need to start searching for the customisation. I suspect, that I need the total number of samples showed in the tooltip to generate a grid. But I dont know where to get this information from. Perhaps I should rephrase the question to: "Which variable in the tooltip stores the total number of samples in the current tooltip"